# C function called recursively fails with strtol_l_internal SIGSEGV

Tags: c, recursion

I am working on some very old code (early 90's) written in C.  Ported to Linux in 2012.  One program uses recursion to read data from a port and assemble the read data into a buffer stored in global storage.  It's defined as:

```
char R_buffer[51000];
```

The function that loads the data into this buffer does a standard linux read system all to
read N bytes of data (max BUFSIZ) into a malloced buffer area.  It is then moved into the above
R_buffer byte by byte.

The protocol being used has a start of message sequence and end of sequence that it expects
in the data stream being read.

The problem being experienced is that the return from the recursive function is failing on
a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) in strto_l_internal as reported by the backtrace produced.

The call to the function where it assigns the return value from the function is as follows:

```
   inbyte = getnewchar(timeout_val);
```

Inbyte is defined as a char.  getnewchar returns a char, it being one of the malloced values in buf.

Note that the read is using a SIGALRM timer to check for blocked data incoming.  Could this
alarm be messing up the returned data somehow??

thx.

Comment: Without [mcve] this question cannot be answered.

Comment: Need something we can play with.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216460/what-is-strtol-l-internal and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/siege/+bug/347815

Comment: turns out it looks like the signal call to register the handler function and set the flags was not initializing the structs properly.  valgrind highlighted this.  fixed it and now it's not crashing.  more testing to do.  but looks promising.  thx valgrind dudes.

Comment: Yep.  No issues all day.  solid now.